# Windows 7 - missing PID in services tab, task manager

Tags: windows-7, services, task-manager, pid

So, as stated in the title, PID tab is missing from services tab in task manager. I need PID in order to find a windows service, which causes lots of hard page faults in my system. Any way to fix that?

Here is a screenshot showing what my issue is.

[image: Task manager issue]

Comment: I don't have the tcp/ip tab on my w7 task manager???

Comment: @Moab I had the TCP/IP tab, because of a program called "prio", which added some additional tabs to task manager.

Comment: I wonder if prio changed that, W7 task manager has that pid column by default.

Comment: @Moab It did. Uninstalling prio brought back all the tabs that were missing.

Answer (score 1):

And what do you know... A program called "Prio", which I used to set priorites and process affinity was causing the issue. Now all the tabs in task manager that I wanted are back.

So, for anyone who stumbles here with the same issue - You might have "prio" installed. I have uninstalled it and it's back to normal. I will see if there are any settings that are needed to be changed in prio, so that all the tabs are shown.

Answer (score 0):

#### Missing PID in services tab, task manager

1. Select the column divider between "Service Name" and "Status"
2. Drag it right - you should see a "Description" Column

   [image]
3. Select the column divider between "Service Name" and "Description"

   [image]
4. Drag it right - you should see a "PID" Column

   [image]

Comment: Unfortunently, this didn't work. The column divider is not present and all I can do is extend the width of the present two tabs.

Comment: @Raytek Try turning off Aero first

Comment: I had it disabled. I turned it back on and it's still the same.

Comment: @Raytek What's strange is that your Task Manager looks different o the Windows 7 Task Manager. I don't have a TCP/IP tab for example.

Comment: Yeah... I have installed a program called "prio" sometime ago, so I can set process priorities and affinity permanently. I will try removing it tomorrow and see if that will fix it.

Comment: Just replace Task Manager with [ProcessHacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) - task manager replacement on steroids, including priority and affinity settings and much more ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help. You pointed out that my task manager is looking different(which for some reason I didn't notice) and that made me think about prio.
And also - I converted my comment to an answer as you suggested :)

Comment: @Raytek Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)